# My PC restarts when watching movies

Tags: 12.10, video, restart

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I always keep my computer updated. Now, for some strange reason, whenever I start watching any movie, the computer restarts randomly. I tried watching with VLC, totem and mplayer. Result is the same. Can anybody tell me what can be possibly wrong? And there must be some log files including informations during the restarts. Can someone tell me where I can find those logs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that hapends when no cd in drive ?

Comment: Upload `/var/log/syslog` to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and post link here.

Answer (score 0):

To start:

```
/var/log/syslog - main system log file.
/var/crash - program crashes, look for anything with the right timestamp
/var/log/Xorg.*.log - GUI log files.  Look for one that matches the right time.
```

It could very well be a graphic card bug.  I would make sure your graphics drivers are up to date, and if so, file a launchpad bug.  So much of movie playback is hardware accelerated now, that subtle bugs can creep in.

You will probably also want to clarify in your question what you mean by restart.  Does the full system reboot, or just the user interface crash and you go back to the login screen?

The following guides have been helpful to me when debugging system crashes.  To be clear, I think you have a genuine bug of some kind, and I think you should file it upstream.  I know that doesn't help you watch movies. :(

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash

I don't see anything obvious in your log files.  A true kernel crash will not show up in log files usually, and if find that is what you have, you will need to enable the following to make forward progress:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe

Sorry that you are having this trouble. :(

Comment: I examined these logs. /var/crash does not exist in my PC. App crashes are stored in apport log perhaps? Now, to me these seems fine. But I am including the logs here:
syslog: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1392670/)
Xorg.0.log: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1392686/)
Xorg.1.log: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1392693/)

By restart I meant a full system reboot.

I don't have a graphics card. I have 64MB graphic memory built-in in my Intel G31/33 Express Chipset Motherboard. Everyday I run an apt-get update && apt-get update so graphics drivers are alright I suppose. @dpb

Comment: During movie playback, top shows CPU load average is normal. Bellow 1.00 in my Core 2 Duo processor.

Comment: Your built-in graphics chip in your motherboard likely provids hardware acceleration in this case.  Doesn't have to be an external card to be considered a graphics card, just pointing that out. :) Thanks for the log files.  I would update your answer with them so others can more easily see.